# nopcommerce 3.9 plugin async controller action not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

I am writing a plugin which has controller action Async but when calling that route it is not hitting,

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> HelloWord() {}
```

It is registered as a normal route in routeprovider how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason not to hit the controller method. It seems it is a get method so you can try /controllername/HelloWord. If it is at your plugin then make sure that your plugin is build successfully and installed.